# how to compile the code through a separate standard terminal window?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have visual studio code and I want to compile the code in the standard mac os terminal, what do I need to do for this?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us more information, what languages you're trying to compile ?

Comment: c++ https://ibb.co/w4MfZ1T, just want to change the compiler from internal to external